# Grails rest plugin not encoding ampersand

Tags: rest, grails

I'm using the [Grails rest plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest), and having issues with parameters containing an ampersand. Here is an example of my query:

```
def query = [
    method: 'artist.getinfo',
    artist: 'Matt & Kim',
    format: 'json'
]

withRest(uri:'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/') {
    def resp = get(path: '/2.0/', query: query)
}
```

I think that the get method should automatically URL encode the parameters in query - it correctly converts spaces to '+'. However, it leaves the ampersand as is, which is incorrect (it should be encoded to %26).

I tried manually encoding the artist name before calling get, but then the rest plugin encodes the percent sign!

I turned on logging for the rest client, so I can see what URLs it's requesting.
Originally: `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Matt+&+Kim&format=json`

If I manually encode the name: `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Matt+%2526+Kim&format=json`

Do I need to set an encoding type? (the last.fm API specifies UTF-8) Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 0.7, the rest plugin is using a version of [HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/download.html) which has issues encoding (and decoding) the ampersand character.

There is a [JIRA Issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPREST-7) about this with a suggested workaround (upgrading HTTPBuilder to >= 0.5.2)